# When to free a GObject?

Tags: memory-management, glib, gobject

When to unref a GObject and when to free it?
The [GObject tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-destruction.html) states that a GObject should be unrefed **and** freed, but shouldn't a GObject actually free itself *if and only if* its refcount drops to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial describes how and when a custom-made GObject class should free its internal data. Specifically, the difference between the `dispose` method and the `finalize` method.

When you *create* a GObject, you should *only* unref it and *never* free it, or you'll bypass the reference counting system altogether and maybe cause a crash somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the "self->priv->a_string" in the finalize function with "self->priv->an_object" in the dispose function. This would mean that the object is unrefed **and** freed. My fault.